# Get top 3 entries for each game_index

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a (simplified) table named `source`:

```
game_index  int,
rating      int,
attributes  varchar(42)
```

And now I'm looking for a select command, that extracts the top 3 records (`rating`) for each game (`game_index`). I want to store the results into another table (called `max`, same table layout). So multiple SQL commands are possible.

Without `game_index` it is easy:

```
INSERT INTO max
SELECT * FROM source
ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 3
```

How to combine it with `GROUP BY game_index`?
Any ideas?

Additional table members or temporary tables are possible.

Comment: What if there are ties?

Comment: mysql versoin please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you would do:

```
 INSERT INTO max (. . . )  -- list the columns here
    SELECT . . .  -- list the columns here
    FROM (SELECT s.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY game_index ORDER BY rating DESC) as seqnum
          FROM source s
         ) s
    WHERE seqnum <= 3;
```

This is harder in earlier versions.  One method that works if `rating` is unique is:

```
INSERT INTO max ( . . . )  -- list columns here
    SELECT . . . 
    FROM source s
    WHERE s.rating >= ANY (SELECT s2.rating
                           FROM source s2
                           WHERE s2.game_index = s.game_index
                           ORDER BY s2.rating DESC
                           LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
                          );
```